# Vue 3 v-model does not update value within an array

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I'm building a baisc app using VUE whwere I perform this actions:

- downlaod a list of items from a database (supabase) and save in an array
- list the array in a page with some editable fields
- save the updated value back to the database

To do that I use v-for and v-model but it does not work as expected.
The problem seems to be the v-model not working for the values within an array

I reproduced the problem with a basic array and without using v-for with a static array and usign v-model

```
<script setup lang="ts">
let ingredienti: { nome: string, value: number }[] = [
    { "nome": "frist", value: 1 },
    { "nome": "second", value: 2 },
] 
</script>
  
<template>
    <div>
        <p>
            <input tpe="text" v-model="ingredienti[0].nome" />
        </p>
        <p>Vlaue is: {{ ingredienti[0].nome }}</p>
        <p>
            <input tpe="text" v-model="ingredienti[1].nome" />
        </p>
        <p>Value is: {{ ingredienti[1].nome }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

The use of v-model should bind the value of the text box with the value of the array but this does not work.

Seems quite a typical scenario where I take a list of item from a database, change the value and at the end submit the result to the database.

Any suggestion to have the v-modal working within an array or to have an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not reactive. You should use `reactive` or `ref` to make it reactive.

For arrays you should better use `ref`

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref } from 'vue'

let ingredienti: { nome: string, value: number }[] = ref([
    { "nome": "frist", value: 1 },
    { "nome": "second", value: 2 },
]) 
</script>
```

Check the `<input type="number" v-model="ingredienti[1].value" />` field in the playground

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const App = { 
  setup() {
    let ingredienti = ref([
        { "nome": "frist", value: 1 },
        { "nome": "second", value: 2 },
    ])
    return { ingredienti }   
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
ingredienti : {{ ingredienti }}
<div>
    <p>
        <input type="text" v-model="ingredienti[0].nome" />
    </p>
    <p>Vlaue is: {{ ingredienti[0].value }}</p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" v-model="ingredienti[1].nome" />
    </p>
    <p>Value is: {{ ingredienti[1].value }}</p>
    <input type="number" v-model="ingredienti[1].value" />
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```